# how to set/write svn property

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using svn 
And directories are like

    `/aaa ( including .abc files) 
    /bbb 
    /ccc 
    /aaa-011 (including .abc files) 
    /aaa-023 
    /bbb-011
    /ccc-011
    ....`

My task: ignore .abc files in /aaa-* (meaning wildcard) 
But do not ignore .abc files in /aaa 
I have tried: set property each /aaa-### files.

Please, tell me how to set if you could set better.

Comment: Sorry my sending environment or my skill are not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, understand what *ignore* does: It ignores files ***not already added to the repository***. You cannot ignore files or directories already added to the repository.

Second, just because you ignored a file or directory doesn't mean it cannot be added.

This might make your life a wee bit easier. You can add the ignore to ignore all files/directories to ignore `.abc`, but still add it to the `aaa` directory, or if it is already added to the `.aaa` directory, not worry about it.

Until Subversion 1.8, there was no way to globally ignore except by setting the global ignore setting in the user's configuration (in `$HOME/.subversion/config` on Unix/Mac/Linux or `%USERPROFILE%\.subversion\config` in Windows). In Subversion 1.8 and above, you now have a property called `svn:global-ignore` that sets the ignore pattern for the current directory and all subdirectories under that directory.

Comment: Thank you answer. I could not explain my task perfectly. My task: someone added .abc files to /aaa-### but I don't want to checkout it(shown as "ignore"). So how do I set property?

Comment: But still I want to checkout  .abc files in /abc.

Comment: You can. The ignore doesn't ignore files that are already committed inside the repository. All ignore does is prevent you from ***accidentally*** adding the file or directory. For example, you don't want to add in the `bin` directory by accident, you ignore it. Doing a `svn add *` won't add it. Doing a `svn status` won't show it as a `?`. However, you can add it via `svn add bin`, and once it's in, you'll see its status as if you didn't have the ignore.